# dataclasses.Field doesn't resolve type annotation to actual type

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

The documentation for the [Field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.Field) class of python's standard [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module specifies only:

> Its documented attributes are:
>
> - [...]
> - type: The type of the field.

To me, it seems to mean that the field will contain the type itself, and not only it's name in the form of a string.

However, it seems that it simply copies the type annotation as is, making it quite useless.

Example:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass 
class C: 
    c: 'C'

dataclasses.fields(C)[0].type # This returns the string 'C'
typing.get_type_hints(C)['c'] # This returns the class C, as expected
```

The problem even occurs systematically when using [PEP563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) type annotations.

Is this a bug in the dataclasses module? Is this the expected behavior? If so, how do I retrieve a type object given a Field instance?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you *expect* the `dataclass` module to do with the type? It's handling the type hint exactly the way every other type hint is handled.

Comment: Well, I would expect it to do what it specifies in its documentation, that is, returning the type itself, and not the type annotation.

Answer (score 14):

This is deliberate. Resolving type hints at import time is *expensive*, especially when `from __future__ import annotations` has been used to disable resolving them in the first place.

Initially, the addition of the PEP 563 to Python 3.7 broke dataclasses when you used the `from __future__ import annotations` switch and included [`ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables) or [`InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) type annotations for fields; these would not be resolved at this point and remained a string. This was already a problem before PEP 563 if you explicitly used strings, see [dataclasses issue #92](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/92#issuecomment-382473127). This became a [Python bug, #33453](https://bugs.python.org/issue33453), once dataclasses made it into Python 3.7 proper.

The 'parent' project, `attrs`, which inspired `dataclasses`, [also had this issue to solve](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/361#issuecomment-380370996). There, Łukasz Langa (co-author of most of the type hinting peps, including PEP 563), states:

> OK, so I tried the above and it seems it's a nuclear option since it forces all annotations to be evaluated. This is what I wanted to avoid with `from __future__ import annotations`.

and in the [discussion on the pull request that fixed issue 33453](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/6768#discussion_r187813919), Eric Smith, author of `dataclasses`, stated:

> I've been researching doing just that. I think @ambv's point is that it introduces a performance hit due to calling eval on every field, while the point of string annotations is to remove a performance hit.

Moreover, there were other problems; you can't evaluate all type hints at import time, not when they use forward references:

> In addition to the performance issue, in the following case (without a `__future__` statement and without dataclasses), I get an error on `get_type_hints()` because `C` is undefined when `get_type_hints()` is called. This is [python/typing#508](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/508). Notice that where `get_type_hints()` is called in this example is exactly where `@dataclass` is going to run and would need to call the stripped down `get_type_hints()`.

So in the end, all that `dataclasses` does is do is apply string heuristics to the annotations, and will not load them for you.

To retrieve the type, just use `get_type_hints()` on the class itself, and us the field `.name` attribute as the key into the result:

```
resolved = typing.get_type_hints(C)
f = dataclasses.fields(C)[0]
ftype = resolved[f.name]
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer ! Did no one envision to resolve the annotations when `dataclasses.fields` is called, as it is the only way for a user to create a Field instance ? It would incur no performance penalty at import time, and would make the .type field consistent.  Without it, I don't see any case where this field could do anything useful...

Comment: @lovasoa: (sorry, this dropped of my radar for longer than I'd have liked): The implementation needs to have `dataclasses.Fields()` instances to generate the class object, which includes a `__init__` method with those same type annotations, and potential class variables and init-only fields. So when the `@dataclass` decorator is executed, the `Field()` instances are created too.