# How to get attributes in class that extends from the same parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

There are a few classes that I defined

```
class Animal:
    def do_parent_method():
        pass

class Monkey(Animal):
    pass


class Elephant(Animal):
    pass


@dataclass
class Zoo:
    monkey: Monkey= Monkey()
    elephant: Elephant = Elephant()
    start_time: datetime = None
    name: str = 'Not important at all'

    def data_format(self):
        items = [self.monkey, self.elephant]  # Now I hard code here
        for item in items:
            do_something()
```

The key point is about how to get attributes in the `Zoo` class

Maybe someday, we will add another animal in our code

```
@dataclass
class Zoo:
    monkey: Monkey= Monkey()
    elephant: Elephant = Elephant()
    start_time: datetime = None
    name: str = 'Not important at all'

    def data_format(self):
        items = [get the attributes that extends from Animal]  # How to do?
        for item in items:
            do_parent_method()
```

For now I just want `items` to be a list, so that I could for-loop it.

Or if you have another good idea is also good for me.

#### Note:

The all the attributes in Zoom class will only have some str, datetime, int type. All the other instance will be the children class of Animal class.

#### Fixed:

Accidentally entered 'zoo' into 'zoom'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

Comment: @Pynchia: I don't see how that's relevant. Simple `isinstance` checking works fine here, you don't need the exhaustive set of all subclasses to do it.

Comment: Given the OP wants all the animals, why have to instantiate a class var each by name and hard-coded? Instantiate them automatically, one per subclass and store them in the list `items = [s() for s in Animal.__subclasses__()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `dataclasses.fields` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) can return field information about a class, including both the name and type of each field. So your `list` comprehension can be written:

```
items = [getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self) if issubclass(field.type, Animal)]
```

The flaw here is that it doesn't work for string annotations, which includes all cases where the module uses `from __future__ import annotations`. You could use the tricks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55937859/364696) to resolve to the actual type, or you could just unconditionally get all the fields, then filter them with `isinstance` checks (that verify the runtime type, not the annotated type that can be blithely ignored at runtime):

```
items = [attr for attr in (getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self)) if isinstance(attr, Animal)]
```

Comment: It's not clear if the OP wants the instances of the Animal subclasses to appear in the dataclass, to be used e.g. `zoom_inst.dog`. Zoom is a dataclass after all.

Comment: @Pynchia: Seems pretty clear. They want the dynamically generated version of `[self.monkey, self.elephant]` where it pulls whatever attributes the dataclass has that happen to be `Animal` subclasses without having to explicitly list them one by one.

Comment: Ok, then i will undelete my answer

Comment: @Pynchia: Your answer is *creating* a bunch of *new* instances of `Animal` subclasses, not pulling any of the *existing* `Animal` subclass instances attached as attributes to the existing instance of the `Zoom` dataclass. I'm not sure where you got the idea that creating additional instances of the subclasses makes any sense.

Comment: I understand the OP wants all the Animals. So why type them all in? Unless they also need to appear as attrs of the dataclass. And that is why I would set such names automatically if that is the case

Comment: @Pynchia: The title of the question literally begins "How to get attributes" (and once again mentions that they're dealing with attributes, not just random `Animal` instances in the final paragraph); of course they need to be attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203566/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-pynchia).